# Laravel Eloquent Relationship with Pivot Table and Conditionals

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Looking to implement a pivot table relationship within an Eloquent model, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

To illustrate, assume we have a system that tracks which movies are playing at which theaters.  Also assume that theaters can have promotional discounts to reduce the ticket price.  Some discounts might have restrictions (minimum ticket price or only movies rated G, etc) and discounts may or may not be combinable.

DB structure:

```
movies (id, title...)
theaters (id, name,...)
discounts (id, theater_id, discount_amount, min_price, can_combine)
theater_movies (id, movie_id, theater_id, ticket_price)
movie_discounts (id, movie_id, discount_id)
```

Laravel TheaterMovie model

```
class TheaterMovie extends Model
{
   public function discounts()
      return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Discount::class,
            MovieDiscount::class,
            'movie_id', // Foreign key on movie_discounts table...
            'id', // Foreign key on discounts table...
            'movie_id', // Local key on theater_movies table...
            'discount_id' // Local key on movie_discounts table...
        ) 
}
```

But this is not capturing theater_movies.theater_id = discounts.theater_id relationship and ideally would also check ticket_price with min_price.

[image: relation]

Comment: The `hasManyThrough` relationship doesn't actually use a pivot, it's `belongsToMany` that does. Think of `hasManyThrough` as `A` has many `B` and `B` has many `C` so `A` has many `C` though `B` .

Comment: return $this->belongsToMany(Discount::class, 'movie_discount','movie_id','discount_id','movie_id'); 
But where can I use the theater_movies.theater_id = discounts.theater_id?  Would some sort of scope work?

Comment: The TheaterMovie class is pivotal to listing the same movie from all theaters with prices adjusted to any present discounts.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier to use a simple relationship on the Theater and Movie models rather than try to bring in the TheaterMovie class.

So for example, on the Theater class, you would have a relationship to the movies like so:

```
public function movies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Movie")->orderBy('name');
}
```

And then to get your pivots you could do a similar relationship but add the pivots right on the Theater model:

```
public function discounts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Discount")->withPivot('discount_amount', 'min_price', 'can_combine')->orderBy('name');
}
```

From here, when you call the relationship from the Theater model, you can use the pivots like so:

```
$theater->pivot->discount_amount;
```

and so forth.  You can put a similar (or even same) discounts relationship on the movies table if you like so you can grab the info from the other related model.